# Google AMP and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

Is this the correct coding to add into my Google AMP article? I tried to submit to Google AMP and there is no error but the article will not come out in the Google Analytics when I browse my article from my handphone.

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
         <script type="application/json">
          {
            "vars": {
            "account": "UA-XXXXXX"
             },
            "triggers": {
            "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview",
             "vars": {
               "title" : "GAMP-"+ "Title of my page"
              }
              }
              }
          }
             </script>
       </amp-analytics>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This question would be better if it was asked on codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to documentation available at

[Google amp-analytics documentation](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics)

You will need to include the script reference in the head of your html document. Your whole amp html page will need to be validated as well. I suggest going through the starting documentation to create your first google-amp validated page and then add the analytics. Find that guide here

[Hello World Google-amp](https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/)